# Anti-fraud module

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating an anti-fraud module and have a question .
How do I run my module only after the payment gateway perform their functions?
I need to be next because if the gateway does not accept I will not send to my anti-fraud api .

ps: translated from google translator

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you want to separate authorize and capture. The payment gateway will give you a response after a successful authroization - meaning it holds the funds until you send a capture request.

Your anti-fraud module should run after authroize, which is in Magento - generally creation of an order. A creation of an invoice is generally capture, which is taking the authorized amount into your account.

You should be changing the payment gateway settings so that it only does `authorize` and not `authroize & capture`. Once you do this, the event to look for is `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`.

The module you build should have an observer listening to that event - if it passes your anti-fraud test, then it should instruct Magento to create an invoice & capture.